# Mongoid: unique index for embedded documents

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to create a unique field for embedded documents:

```
class Chapter
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title
end
class Book
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  embeds_many :chapters
  index({ 'name' => 1 }, { unique: true })
  index({ 'name' => 1, 'chapters.title' => 1 }, { unique: true, sparse: true })
  # index({ 'name' => 1, 'chapters.title' => 1 }, { unique: true })
end
```

I run the task: `rake db:mongoid:create_indexes`

```
I, [2017-02-22T08:56:47.087414 #94935]  INFO -- : MONGOID: Created indexes on Book:
I, [2017-02-22T08:56:47.087582 #94935]  INFO -- : MONGOID: Index: {:name=>1}, Options: {:unique=>true}
I, [2017-02-22T08:56:47.087633 #94935]  INFO -- : MONGOID: Index: {:name=>1, :"chapters.title"=>1}, Options: {:unique=>true, :sparse=>true}
```

But it doesn't work as I would expect...

```
Book.new( name: 'A book', chapters: [ { title: 'title1' }, { title: 'title1' }, { title: 'title2' } ] ).save  # no errors

Book.new( name: 'Another book', chapters: [ { title: 'title2' } ] ).save
b = Book.last
b.chapters.push( Chapter.new( { title: 'title2' } ) )
b.save  # no errors
```

Any idea?

UPDATE: Ruby 2.4.0, Mongo 3.2.10, Mongoid 5.2.0 | 6.0.3 (trying both)

UPDATE2: I add also the tests I made directly with mongo client:

```
use books
db.books.ensureIndex({ title: 1 }, { unique: true })
db.books.ensureIndex({ "title": 1, "chapters.title": 1 }, { unique: true, sparse: true, drop_dups: true })
db.books.insert({ title: "Book1", chapters: [ { title: "Ch1" }, { title: "Ch1" } ] })  # allowed?!
db.books.insert({ title: "Book1", chapters: [ { title: "Ch1" } ] })
b = db.books.findOne( { title: 'Book1' } )
b.chapters.push( { "title": "Ch1" } )
db.books.save( b )  # allowed?!
db.books.findOne( { title: 'Book1' } )
db.books.insert({ title: "Book2", chapters: [ { title: "Ch1" } ] })
```

UPDATE3: I made more tests but I didn't succeed, this [link](http://joegornick.com/2012/10/25/mongodb-unique-indexes-on-single-embedded-documents/) helped but the problem remains

Comment: Try index "chapters.name" => 1

Comment: @GennadyGrishkovtsov: there is no name field in chapters - BTW same result

Comment: Did you read https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/6.0.0/mongoid-indexes/ ?

Comment: In that page there's no example with a unique index on embedded documents

Answer (score -1):

You should use **drop_dups**

```
class Category
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :title, type: String

  embeds_many :posts

  index({"posts.title" => 1}, {unique: true, drop_dups: true, name: 'unique_drop_dulp_idx'})
end


class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, type: String
end
```

Rails console:

```
irb(main):032:0> Category.first.posts.create(title: 'Honda S2000')
=> #<Post _id: 58adb923cacaa6f778215a26, title: "Honda S2000">
irb(main):033:0> Category.first.posts.create(title: 'Honda S2000')
Mongo::Error::OperationFailure: E11000 duplicate key error collection: mo_development.posts index: title_1 dup key: { : "Honda S2000" } (11000)
```

Comment: Same problems that I reported in my question. And the second test fails completely even if I have a different title

Comment: hmm, it works. Did you rebuild indexes? Try db:mongoid:remove_indexes & db:mongoid:create_indexes

Comment: Your code here doesn't work (save gives no errors). What version of Mongo / Mongoid / Ruby are you using?

Comment: Rails 5, mongoid 6

Comment: Also, you can try use mongo (/usr/local/bin/mongo) to understand that the indexes work

Comment: I have already tried but I have the same problems - I add them to the question